# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When i'm trying to connecting to mysql. getting this error.

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

Comment: What is your DB host?  On local machine? Anything PHP error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 110 is "connection timed out". If you're trying to connect via TCP sockets, make sure that the MySQL port (3306 by default) is not firewalled off.